# Why COD not showing in checkout page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have enable the COD payment option from admin and when I checked this on checkout page it is not showing. There is another payment option which payu it is also enabled and it is working fine. PFB Screenshot for the same

[image]
[image]

Is there I have to change anything in code so that COD option should be available? Please guide me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried disabling all services except COD?

Comment: @AliZia Yes when I did it shows error message on checkout "Warning: No Payment options are available. Please contact us for assistance!"

Comment: Check zone assignment for this method. Set it to All Zones for starters.

Answer (score 6):

My issue ended up being that my products were all set to not require shipping. Obviously if the cash is going to be received on delivery the product has to actually be delivered

Comment: My items are marked as require shipping, and yet I have the same problem as OP.

Comment: Solved for me!!

Comment: Solved mine too, thanks a million you saved my day literally :D

Comment: `set to not require shipping` -- did you mean they were marked as Virtual?

Answer (score 0):

go to payments >    enable 'Cash On Delivery' -> 'manage' COD > tick mark 'enable Cash On Delivery'-> In 'Enable for shipping methods' enter the *shipping methods* containing the COD available areas/zip/pin codes.
This is the simple way of making COD available on checkout page.
if some orders didn't show COD ,make sure the Zip/pin code is in one of the shipping methods entered in the option 'Enable for shipping methods'.

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel click on catalog->product and click on edit then select data tab there you will see 'Requires Shipping' radio button, just check on yes then you can be able to see COD in your payment method section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WooCommerce subscriptions on your store, some payment gateways won't show because they don't have "Automatic Renewal" capability.

In order to fix this, please goto WooCommerce > Settings > Subscriptions

Here, in the Renewals section, check the box "Accept Manual Renewals".

[WooCommerce subscriptions - enable manual renewals.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4zxI.png)

With manual renewals, a customer's subscription is put on-hold until they login and pay to renew it.

You can also disable automatic payments if needed.

This has solved the issue for me.